# Google OnEdit Script for Multiple Columns not Consecutive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help regarding this code which was sent to me via a link on google spread sheets.

The code is working perfectly however it only works on a single column (column A). I was hoping someone could help on editing the code to make it work on multiple columns which may or may not be consecutive. For example, columns A to E and column K to O.

```
function onEdit() {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() == "1" && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()=="1") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue('=CHAR(9745)');
  }
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() == "0" && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getColumn()=="1") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue('=CHAR(9744)');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the column check (the second parts of the conditionals) to make it work on any column.
It is also better to use the event object passed into the function as the active range can change during the execution.

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  if(e.value == "1") {
    e.range.setValue('=CHAR(9745)');
  } else if(e.value == "0") {
    e.range.setValue('=CHAR(9744)');
  }
}
```

If you want specific ranges to have this feature you can change the conditional to something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  if([1,2,3].indexOf(e.range.getColumn()) > -1) {
    if (e.value == 1) {
      e.range.setValue('=CHAR(9745)');
    } else if(e.value == "0") {
      e.range.setValue('=CHAR(9744)');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Robin!

Thanks for your reply.

I tried to use the modified codes you posted but I am given a TypeError when I run it on google sheets. To be exact, this is what is shown:

Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "CheckBox")

Comment: did you add `e` as a parameter to the function definition?

Comment: I basically copied and pasted the second code you shared the one which can be used for specific ranges. I didn't change anything about it since I'm not familiar with code syntax at all.

Is there anything that I should alter on your code to fit my sheet?

Comment: Are you running it in the debugger? That won't work you'll need to actually do the edits

Comment: Can you please help me where I need to edit anything?
I thought the only part that needs editing are the values 1, 2, and 3 which are for the columns.

Comment: Yes, you edit the column 1,2, or 3 and the script should run automatically.

Comment: I tried it again and changed 1, 2, and 3 with 5, 6 and 7 but I still get the same error when I click RUN on the script editor. If I would just save and close it, nothing happens on my google sheet file. I made the file public, please help me check it..

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11dUuqwUdDRQBD0Tklxfr8r90-OoBcDK_7hy7RpcLGAw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's an onEdit trigger, you edit the spreadsheet and the script runs automatically and changes the content, you're not supposed to run it from the script editor. I just created a copy of your spreadsheet and it works well.

Comment: Thanks man! I just didn't understand that I don't need to run it instead I just have to save it. Now it's working perfectly! 

By the way, does this type of script only affect the current sheet and not the other sheets that are opened in the same file?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, can you explain? It works for every sheet but you can just add an if to immediately stop the function if the sheet is not the one you want the function to work on for example.

Comment: For example I have two or more sheets on the same spreadsheet file, and I only want to run the script to function on Sheet 1 and not on Sheet 2.

Comment: `if (e.range.getSheet().getName() !== "Sheet1"){return;}`